# Automated 9GAG comments with Python (selenium) get deleted?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests

I wrote a Python script to automate the process of adding comments with selenium each comment is posted automatically one after the other with a second in between them. However none of those comments I automated on one post were there after some time, there was only one comment of mine, that I had manually typed. How does 9GAG do it? Is there any way to bypass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to 9gag FAQ (https://about.9gag.com/faq/#six-two) you can see the following:

> **Comment Failings: I can't see my comments anymore. Why?**
>
> This could be for one of two reasons:
>
> - The auto spam filter identified your comments as spams OR
> - The community/other users downvoted and/or reported your comments
>
> **Multiple failings: I can't upload/I can't comment anymore. Why?**
>
> It’s very likely your account is suspended or banned because you have
>   violated our 9GAG rules.

As for the 9gag rules (https://about.9gag.com/rules):

> **No spamming, manipulation and multiple account abuse**
>
> Everyone hates spam. Don’t post large amounts of untargeted, unwanted
>   or repetitive content and comments in order to increase views.
>   Creating multiple accounts with overlapping uses or in order to evade
>   the temporary or permanent ban of a separate account is not allowed.

... so, I would say you got detected either by the short period of time between your comments, or the content of them. To try out this possibilities, I would make a script which sleeps a random amount of time between comments, and generates random comments of random lenghts:

```
import random
import time
import string

while True:
    random_comment = ' '.join([random.choice(string.printable) for i in range(random.randint(10,100))])
    random_time = random.randint(1, 10)
    time.sleep(random_time)
    upload_comment(random_comment)
```

Comment: Wow a quick and helpful reply! Thanks a lot! I'll try your suggestions

Comment: The content might be repetitive for those em two loops. But I have already modified the script, now I've scraped a list of umm "negative" words from another website and stored them in a list. I'll try it again to see if 320 something different words result in the same situation and will let you know, if you're interested. After that, I can even set the 'time.sleep()' to a random integer between 1 to 5..Hopefully my account won't be banned :p

Comment: Let me know how it goes! I’m always very interested in successful automatizations with selenium, I use it a lot myself. You wouldn’t believe the lack of security measures against bots. Not for trolling, but to gather information as well. It’s fun as well!

Comment: Ahh thanks I will keep you posted. Your experience with selenium can be my guiding light into automation(with selenium) "enlightenment"! And oh my, I won't call it trolling, you can look at it as umm...an efficient way to uh lets say mitigate the acts of explicit trolls  :D...I've used BeautifulSoup for scraping stuff it is indeed very useful. If possible do give me a summary of your work with selenium or even Python :) Thanks again!

Comment: Oh this is embarrassing...It did work, however after about 47 comments I received a prompt stating that I have to wait for a variable amount of time(time wasn't specified :p) before I can post another comment.

Comment: And no it wasn't the issue of redundancy in the content of the comments, they are still there btw, my previous comments I mean :p my bad, I checked an entirely different post for those comments hence wasn't able to find them...In my defence however I was doing a half a dozen other things simultaneously at the time

Comment: Update : Once you reach the comment quota on 9GAG, you cannot post more than 1 comment per day I think, because I ran the script earlier today posted about 100 comments or so and them BAMM comment quota done. And after that I had to wait about 8 hours until I could post a comment and then after that I posted one comment manually again I had to wait because I was allowed to post only one comment, and then again a few minutes earlier I posted another comment and now I have to wait for 12 hours until I can post another comment.